Announcing the July–August 2024 topic challenge: Maryse Condé
In accordance with our meta agreement to have topic challenges
and a later meta agreement to have topic challenges lasting for two months and overlapping by one month,
it is time to announce the July–August 2024 topic challenge.
Based on the number of votes (+6, -1), our next topic challenge will be
the works of Maryse Condé

What's a topic challenge?
See the meta posts linked above, and also this main Meta post.
In short, during July and August 2024 you are invited to try to get hold of one or more of the works by Maryse Condé, read them, and ask or answer questions about them.
Participation is not obligatory in any sense, and questions on other works are more than welcome during July and August too;
they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.
How can I take part?
By getting hold of one or more of the works by Maryse Condé and

asking good questions about it or
answering questions that have been posted as part of this challenge or
writing a review of the book on our Tumblr blog.

Questions about these works should be tagged maryse-conde and french-language.
We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.
Below is Tsundoku's
presentation:

Maryse Condé (1934–2024) was a Guadeloupean/French novelist, playwright and critic. Her "novels explore racial, gender and cultural issues in a variety of historical eras and locales" (Wikipedia). She won awards for several of her works, which include the following:

Hérémakhonon (1976), her first novel, "was so controversial that it was pulled from the shelves after six months because of its criticism over the success of African socialism".
Segu (French: Ségou: Les murailles de terre, 1985) is set in the 19th-century Bambara or Ségou Empire of Mali and is the novel that brought her to prominence.
The Children of Segu (French: Ségou: la terre en miettes) is a sequel to the previous novel.
I, Tituba: Black Witch of Salem (French: Moi, Tituba, Sorcière…Noire de Salem, 1986) creates a character, Tituba, who was thrown into the same cell as Hester Prynne from Nathanial Hawthorne's The Scarlet Letter.
Windward Height (French: La migration des coeurs, 1995) is a reworking of Emily Brontë’s Wuthering Heights.


What's next?

Vote for the next topic challenge or propose your own!


List of all questions posted in this topic challenge

What is the meaning of "chabeen" in Conde's "The Gospel According to the New World"? by Clara Díaz Sanchez, 27/07/2024 (9 votes, 305 views, HNQ, 1 answer);
What is the meaning of the brown flower in Condé's "The Gospel According to the New World"? by Clara Díaz Sanchez, 04/08/2024 (4 votes, 123 views, 1 answer);
Meaning of "The Word that Descends by Night" in "Segu" by Clara Díaz Sanchez, 23/08/2024 (4 votes, 130 views, 1 answer);
Usage of 1st and 3rd person narration in Condé's "Crossing the Mangrove" by Clara Díaz Sanchez, 24/08/2024 (3 votes, 44 views, no answer);
Is a character's name in Segu a reference to another author? by Clara Díaz Sanchez, 31/08/2024 (2 votes, 17 views, no answer);
Is the miracle in Sarojini's story an allusion? by Tsundoku, 31/08/2024 (2 votes, 18 views, no answer).


The highest-voted of these is What is the meaning of "chabeen" in Conde's "The Gospel According to the New World"? with a score of 9 at the end of August.
The most viewed is What is the meaning of "chabeen" in Conde's "The Gospel According to the New World"?*, with approximately 305 views by the end of August.
Three questions received at least one answer.

Reviews submitted to our Tumblr blog: L’évangile du nouveau monde by Maryse Condé, 31 August 2024, Tsundoku.
